# Original url from twitter short url

Tags: twitter

I need to get the base url or the original url from the short url that is obtained from twitter in the form http://t.co...

Is their any way to get the original base url from this...please suggest

Any kind of help will be appreciated..

Answer (score 1):

Look at this link, https://dev.twitter.com/docs/tweet-entities

Especially "The media entity" part

One of these from api should solve your problem.

- media_url    The URL of the media file (see the `sizes` attribute for
  available sizes)
- media_url_https  The SSL URL of the media file (see the sizes
  attribute for available sizes)
- url  The media URL that was extracted
- display_url  Not a URL but a string to display instead of the media
  URL
- expanded_url     The fully resolved media URL